# allow_url_fopen=0 How to propper check for errors and are there alternatives?

Tags: php, javascript, xml-parsing

> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: http://
>   wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0
>   in /home/vol6/byethost22.com

This host, (free hosting) has disabled this. So i was about looking into a paid options (i assume it's on there could not find anything about it taught. Anyway i then taught, this actually stops execution if the entire script because it later and i might learn out of it, change my code for the better use a java-script fallback or something.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object in

So this is my code:

```
} elseif ( $provider == 'vimeo' ) {
        $vimeo_hash = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' . $id . '.php'));
        $thumbnail = $vimeo_hash[0]['thumbnail_medium'];
} elseif ( $provider == 'bliptv' ) {
        $blip_xml = simplexml_load_file("http://blip.tv/players/episode/$id?skin=rss");
        $blip_result = $blip_xml->xpath("/rss/channel/item/media:thumbnail/@url");
        $thumbnail = (string) $blip_result[0]['url'];

if ( $thumbnail ) {
    if ( ! list( $width_orig, $height_orig ) = getimagesize( $thumbnail ) ) {
        return "ERROR!";
    }
```

getimagesize() produces a error like the very first mentioned

**1.**

Am i right to assume i can't use one of the many other php ways to do this xml processing because the would all fail? If yes, this leads me to a few more questions.

**2.**

I know i can do things like putting the thing inside a if statement like this but how would i be able to detect if the id for the image (if) is actually wrong/not leaded or the function itself is not possible?

```
if ( $blip_xml = simplexml_load_file("http://blip.tv/players/episode/$id?skin=rss") ){
    [...]
}
```

**3.**

I think the code above is valid but i hate how it looks. It looks like i forgot to use a double "==" and just used one. Doing things like this would case php to do the same thing twice right? it is there some caching going on (without extra addition my host/software)

```
if ( simplexml_load_file("http://blip.tv/players/episode/$id?skin=rss" ) ){
    $blip_xml = simplexml_load_file("http://blip.tv/players/episode/$id?skin=rss")
}
```

**4.**

I could do the same thing with javascript, i just need to pull the image and load it as a div background. Should i even bother with php and do a fallback for js and just do it in js in the first place? i found this [simplexml for js script](http://code.google.com/p/simplexmljs/downloads/detail?name=simplexml.march.2011.js&can=2&q=) thats 4k and seems to emulate simplexml in js. Would this be the right way to start? I guess its easy with jquery and i actaully use it atm but later might want to use this without jquery. Or can i do this simple thing even with less code in js?

Comment: shame that blip and vimeo need stupid xml processing to get the video thumbnail. youtube and dailymotion do it the right way. just load them from an url and be happy.

Answer (score 0):

The js wont work for remote hosts as it is bound by the same origin policy as it uses `XMLHttpRequest()`.

You should check the host for curl perhaps that is enabled, then you can use that. /then use `simplexml_load_string()` instead.

Comment: i guess the same goes for JSON?